# Subprocess Popen to run python command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I need to run a python command inside a Popen. The problem is that the command NEEDS to run in python3 and I need it to be portable, which means that I can't really use the `python3` alias for every situation...

I have computers where `python` is already the correct version, and others where the correct one is `python3`. I tried to insert `#!/usr/bin python3` in the beginning of the file and then run as `python` but it didn't work.

I can't modify environment vars to change `python3` to `python`. I would like to know if there is a way to check which one I need to use or a way to change the `python3` to `python` ONLY inside the Popen command...

The Popen command I am trying to run is very simple and no I can't just import the file and use as a class... it needs to be ran through Popen. Also, virtualenv or similars are not an option.

`subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)`

Comment: `shell=True` breaks your code here: What it runs is equivalent to the command `sh -c 'python' 'main.py'`; you can test in a shell that it doesn't work there either (because only the argument immediately after `-c` is treated as a shell script; arguments after that become `$0`, `$1`, etc, but that script doesn't look for them and so they're ignored) -- whereas with `shell=False`, what you run is equivalent to (the shell command) `python main.py`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Really? Can you run `python main.py` directly from your console?

Comment: `python main.py` works at a shell prompt, `sh -c python main.py` does not (for a value of "does not work" wherein the `main.py` argument gets ignored)

Comment: You can also test this at an interactive shell by comparing `echo hello` with `sh -c echo hello`; with the `sh -c` -- as added by Python's `shell=True` -- preceding, the `hello` is ignored, and only an empty line is `echo`ed.

Comment: ...anyhow, moving towards your main question: If you're already changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` on platforms where this is necessary, then the only remaining thing necessary is to run `/path/to/yourscript` instead of `python /path/to/yourscript` so that shebang is honored. So `subprocess.Popen(['./main.py'])` will honor that `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or whatever it is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, I agree that running `sh -c python main.py` on terminal does not work. But, running as I mentioned in the question works normally...

Comment: Which platform are you testing on? (Windows is quite different).

Comment: ...you can test with `subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hello'], shell=True)` to show that the same behavior (re: `hello` being ignored if `shell=True` is given) happens in Python (if on a Unixlike).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am testing on a mac and a windows machine.... maybe the unix is the exceptional case...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179122/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-gabrielle).

Comment: removing the `python` part worked though... thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shebang -- the initial line showing which interpreter to use, such as `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` -- is only honored if you don't explicitly select an interpreter yourself: If you run `python foo.py`, the OS is invoking a specific Python interpreter and passing it `foo.py` as an argument (which it interprets as the name of a script it should run); whereas when you run `./foo.py`, you're telling the OS itself to figure out which interpreter to use to run `foo.py`, which it does by looking at the shebang.

To leave it up to the operating system to select, just explicitly specify the name of your script:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./main.py'], universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: It worked only on mac... even the "shell=True" on the windows does not work... `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` any idea?

Comment: If the PyLauncher tool is available and in the PATH, you should be able to use `py -3 main.py` on Windows. See https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pylauncher -- as I understand, it ships out-of-the-box with Python 3. Windows isn't my native platform, though, so take anything I say about it with a grain of salt.

Comment: See also [PEP-0397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), describing the `py` command on Windows -- among other things, it's intended to be able to read a shebang (normally a UNIX-only thing) and dispatch to the appropriate Python install.